# Is there a way to replicate same edit in every line or between marked lines in a Vim?

Tags: vim, one-liner

My file looks like this

```
a
b
c
d
```

I would like the output of file to be:

```
.a(a)
.b(b)
.c(c)
.d(d)
```

Is there a one liner in vim to do so?

Comment: Does your file really start with a blank line?

Comment: Nopes.  I can add markers.

Comment: I fixed it, no problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a substitution:

```
:%s/.\+/.&(&)/
```

`.\+` to capture non-empty line. `&` is the entire match inside the replacement section

Comment: `:help \+` and `:help s/\&`.

Comment: Am I ill, or 3 people have upvoted this answer without having tested it? It's just a typo, but the right substitution is `:%s/.\+/.&(&)`

Comment: @yolenoyer fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global `:g` to perform on all lines `.` the `norm` command (`^[` is escape key inserted with `<c-v><esc>`):

```
:g/./norm diwi.^[pa()^[P
```

But you can also record your modification with `q` and repeat that with `@` as many times as you like or for a range. See `:h recording`.

`qq` "do your stuff" `q` select your lines and run `norm @q`, for example:

```
:'<,'>norm @q
```

or with g:

```
:g/./norm @q
```